# Android: Skip Current Fragment and loads next

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement display logic in the surveylib Library (https://github.com/AndreiD/surveylib). This is a library to implement a survey app. There will be set of questions and properties in JSON file and this library prepares a set of questions depending on the JSON file.

This library implemented the survey app by using Fragments and ViewPager.  There are different fragments for different types of questionnaires (e.g. fragments folder). I want to incorporate display logic in this library which is some questions might not be displayed depending on the answers received in previous questions. I have created variables in Questions.java (in model folder).

I am struggling with skipping a fragment and load the next one. For example, I want to implement the skip routing in this [FragmentCheckboxes.java](https://github.com/AndreiD/surveylib/blob/master/surveylib/src/main/java/com/androidadvance/androidsurvey/fragment/FragmentCheckboxes.java) file. Based on the answers of the previous question this question with checkboxes might not be displayed. I have added this part so far:

```java
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {


        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            // called here
            Log.d("Checkbox Fragment: ", q_data.getQuestionNo() + " setUserVisibleHint");
            String display_logic=q_data.getDisplayLogic();

            String condition_question=display_logic.split(",")[0];
            String condition_value=display_logic.split(",")[1];
            String response=Answers.getInstance().get_answer(condition_question);
            Log.d("Display Logic", "Question: "+condition_question+", Condition _Value: "+ condition_value+", Response: "+response);
            if(response.equals(condition_value))
            {
                Log.d("Display Logic", "Skipping " + q_data.getQuestionNo());
                Answers.getInstance().put_answer(textview_q_title.getText().toString(), "N/A");
             //   getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContext=getActivity();
               ((SurveyActivity)mContext).go_to_next();

            }
            else
            {
                super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            }

        }
    }
```

go_to_next() function is implemented in SurveyActivity.java. My problem is although it is calling go_to_next() function, this fragment is still visible and when I click next it skips the next question which I don't want. I wan't to skip the current question and load the next one.  More specifically, Let's say we have three questions: Q1, Q2, and Q3. Q1 is radio button and can have two responses: yes and no. If the user selected yes for Q1, we will skip Q2 and display Q3. Otherwise, Q2 will be displayed after Q1.

In this particular case, how can I skip a fragment in android and load the next one?

Answer (score 0):

1.first u need to get the positions of the fragments in view pager adapter
2.then while calling go_to_next()  pass the position of the fragment.
3.in the viewpager activity  where u implemented the interface method call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);` or pos+x